# How to make my compare tool work within Eclipse with Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, libreoffice, uno

I have finshed the logic of comparing two files via the svn plugin of eclipse. I pass the two parameters of the eclipse svn plugin to the sheel script, and passed the parameters to the java program via the sheel script, then use UNO to compare two libreoffice ods file.(libreoffice is in ods format which is a binary file format, and it is not supported by the standard Compare Editor Program of Eclipse.)
But now I need to use git to manage the ods file, how to compare it?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If possible you might want to look into fods (flat ods) which is a single xml file instead of the set of zipped xml files that are an ods file. Sadly we still have not managed to completely eliminate some of the random automatic style name changes.